# does << sign bypass = sign in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :author
  attr_reader :title
  attr_reader :comments
  def initialize(author, title)
    @author = author
    @title = title
    @comments = []
  end
end

book = Book.new("Chuck Palahniuk", "Fight Club")


book.comments << "#{book.title} was a good book" 
book.comments.each do |p|
  puts p
end
# Fight Club was a good book
```

if comments method is just a attr_reader and not attr_writer, why does << appending work? Is it because it bypasses the = sign which is attr_writer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement with `<<` modifies the Array that `book.comments` **references**, it doesn't change `book.comments` itself.

Printing its `object_id` before and after:

```
puts book.comments.object_id
book.comments << "#{book.title} was a good book" 
puts book.comments.object_id
```

You will see it's the same object.

---

Compare with the illegal statement:

```
book.comments = []
```

Comment: This is an accurate explanation. I would add that you can avoid modifying an array's internal state (i.e. using the `<<` method) by calling the [`freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-freeze) method on it.

Comment: @Arup, please elaborate.

Comment: @CarySwoveland We have nothing to (_unfreeze_ it.](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/199639#869481). There are some good discussion on this topic.. But right now, those links are not with me.

Comment: If you don't want to freeze the array (you probably don't), you should probably write a getter method that returns a `dup` rather than use `attr_reader`.

Answer (score 1):

While you have created the `book` object, then only the instance variable `@comments` has been created for the `book` object. Now when you are calling the *writeer* method `comments`, it is giving you the *Array* instance back, which you had assigned to it while instantiating the `book`. Now `Array` has the method `Array#<<` to *append* the new value to the array, and that's what happened when you did `book.comments << "#{book.title} was a good book"`.

```
 book.comments << "#{book.title} was a good book"
 # means
 [] << "#{book.title} was a good book"
 # [] has been returned by book.comments
```